# Stick deep nested element

Tags: javascript, html, css, sticky

I have a very deeply nested `<div>` element. How to render a new element inside this element that will float at the top of the screen (body or html)?

Sticky position is relative to the closest element (parent) and this is not an answer.

If it can not be done with CSS, is there any JS library that can do it?

```
<html>
<body>
  <div>
    <div>element should be sticky to the top of the page</div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a class to a div and give position fixed and top 0 to get the element in the top part of screen.

Also, in this example, I gave body 200vh in order to scroll and see the element fixed on top.

```css
body {
  height: 200vh;
}

.sticky {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
  <div>
    <div class="sticky">element should be sticky to the top of the page</div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```